# DTM not loading Google Universal Analytics tool

Tags: google-analytics, adobe-analytics

I'm having an issue where the Google Universal Analytics tool is not loading at all.  I have added the appropriate embed codes in the head and end of the body of the page. DTM is running, but the tool is not firing.  Here's the site I am working on: https://lenox.companybonline.com

Comment: Please consider putting together a Minimal, Verifiable Example. As it is now, this looks more like spam than a question.

Comment: Also, how are you verifying that the tool is not firing. You should install the GA Debugger tool to see if hits are going through.